# QGIS is not able to find GRASS. Choose the path of installation folder of GRASS

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, installation

I've downloaded and then correctly installed `QGIS 1.7.4` for windows (Win 7 64bit is my version) in `C:\Programs\Quantum GIS`.

But everytime I start QGIS this popup appear: `"QGIS is not able to find the installation of GRASS. Choose the path of the GRASS installation folder".`

I've chosen every installation folder in Quantum GIS but the program not recognise it!
So if I don't choose the folder, I can't use GRASS.
In the installation folder there are a file called `"grass64.bat"`, but not `"grass64.exe"`. Could it be the problem?

I've installed QGIS also in other folder and `D:\Programs\...` but without results.

Comment: If you have multiple installations now, consider to completely lean up the machine first. Otherwise it is difficult to identify the problem. If you use the OSGeo4W installer, it should work (if there are no conflicting installations).

Comment: To clarify, I think what @markusN means by "Lean up", is to uninstall all the versions of QGIS that you have installed, including removing the install directories if they are left behind, and starting from scratch.  Download and run the [OSGeo4W Installer](http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/), which will put all components in the same directory.

Comment: My intention was to say that I've installed QGIS in different directories removing the older one everytime. Now I've started to download OSGeo4W hooping it runs correctly. I can tell you more in some minutes...

Comment: Lean up -> clean up... sorry for the non-editable typo!

Comment: No prob. I've to thank you for your answrs. Unfortunally OSGeo4W NOT runs!!! :( The popup message say: "is not recognise a .bat file" I think I've to convert .bat in .exe. Could it the solution?

Comment: I'd suggest that you post the error on this mailing list: http://lists.osgeo.org/mailman/listinfo/osgeo4w-dev . Real experts are listening there...

Comment: It would be really helpful, if you could list down the QGIS and GRASS files to delete after unistallation, so as to make it a clean uninstall. please specify the files to delete for me, as I am a new QGIS user

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if you ever solved this. In any case, if stuff is messed up under MS-Windows, a clean re-installation of OSGeo4W will solve it (means: removed it well, reinstall then).

Answer (score 0):

The QGIS Windows installer is not putting double quotes around path names that have embedded spaces.  I've submitted a bug report.  See line 88 of my install log below (or search for:  `C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS' is not recognized`).  Looks like lots of people have been stumped by this for quite some time.  Hope this fixes it.

---

```
C:\Program Files\QGIS Valmiera\postinstall.log
OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera
OSGEO4W_STARTMENU=C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\QGIS Valmiera
OSGEO4W_ROOT_MSYS=/C/PROGRA~1/QGIS Valmiera

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera>"C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera"\bin\make-bat-for-py.bat

    Generating .bat files for all .py files in C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera\bin


C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera>set ICON=C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\etc\gui\icons\grass_osgeo.ico 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera>set ICON_CMD=C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\etc\gui\icons\grass_cmd.ico 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera>set BATCH=C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera\bin\grass64.bat 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera>textreplace -std -t "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera"\bin\grass64.bat 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera>textreplace -std -t "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera"\bin\grass64 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera>textreplace -std -t "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera"\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\etc\fontcap 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera>del "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera"\bin\grass64.bat.tmpl 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera>del "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera"\bin\grass64.tmpl 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera>if not 1 == 0 mkdir "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\QGIS Valmiera" 
A subdirectory or file C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\QGIS Valmiera already exists.

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera>if not 1 == 0 nircmd shortcut "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera\bin\nircmd.exe" "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\QGIS Valmiera\GRASS GIS 6.4.3" "GRASS GIS 6.4.3 GUI" "exec hide """C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera\bin\grass64.bat" -wx" "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\etc\gui\icons\grass_osgeo.ico" 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera>if not 1 == 0 nircmd shortcut "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera\bin\grass64.bat" "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\QGIS Valmiera\GRASS GIS 6.4.3" "GRASS GIS 6.4.3 Command Line" "-text" "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\etc\gui\icons\grass_osgeo.ico" 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera>if not 1 == 0 nircmd shortcut "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera\bin\nircmd.exe" "~$folder.desktop$" "GRASS GIS 6.4.3" "exec hide """C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera\bin\grass64.bat" -wx" "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\etc\gui\icons\grass_osgeo.ico" 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera>mkdir "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\QGIS Valmiera" 
A subdirectory or file C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\QGIS Valmiera already exists.

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera>xxmklink "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\QGIS Valmiera\MSYS.lnk"       "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera\apps\msys\msys.bat" " " \ "Minimal SYStem" 7 "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera\apps\msys\msys.ico" 

XXMkLink     ver 1.00    (c)2005 Copyright  Pixelab, Inc.

The shortut created as follows

Shortcut path:     C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\QGIS Valmiera\MSYS.lnk
Target object:     C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera\apps\msys\msys.bat
Arguments;          
Working Directory: \
Description:       Minimal SYStem
Display Mode:      Minimized  (7)
Icon file:         C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera\apps\msys\msys.ico


C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera>xxmklink "C:\ProgramData\Desktop\MSYS.lnk" "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera\apps\msys\msys.bat" " " \ "Minimal SYStem" 7 "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera\apps\msys\msys.ico" 

XXMkLink     ver 1.00    (c)2005 Copyright  Pixelab, Inc.

The shortut created as follows

Shortcut path:     C:\ProgramData\Desktop\MSYS.lnk
Target object:     C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera\apps\msys\msys.bat
Arguments;          
Working Directory: \
Description:       Minimal SYStem
Display Mode:      Minimized  (7)
Icon file:         C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera\apps\msys\msys.ico


C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera>textreplace -std -t apps/msys/etc/fstab 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera>dllupdate -oite -copy -reboot "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera\bin\libeay32.dll" 
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera\bin\libeay32.dll: Version=1.0.1.5
C:\Windows\system32\libeay32.dll: Version=0.0.0.0
Target does not exist, no action.

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera>dllupdate -oite -copy -reboot "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera\bin\ssleay32.dll" 
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera\bin\ssleay32.dll: Version=1.0.1.5
C:\Windows\system32\ssleay32.dll: Version=0.0.0.0
Target does not exist, no action.

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera>textreplace -std -t bin\pyuic4.bat 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera>set OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS Valmiera 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera>textreplace -std -t apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\pyqtconfig.py 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera>call C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera\bin\make-bat-for-py.bat 
'C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera>call "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera"\bin\o4w_env.bat 

'"C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
OSGEO4W home is C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera
Synchronizing CRS database with GDAL/PROJ definitions.
0: src=SOURCE_CRS_CODE dst=source_crs_code idx=2
1: src=TARGET_CRS_CODE dst=target_crs_code idx=3
2: src=REMARKS dst=remarks idx=4
3: src=COORD_OP_SCOPE dst=scope idx=5
4: src=AREA_OF_USE_CODE dst=area_of_use_code idx=6
5: src=DEPRECATED dst=deprecated idx=12
6: src=COORD_OP_METHOD_CODE dst=coord_op_method_code idx=13
7: src=DX dst=p1 idx=14
8: src=DY dst=p2 idx=15
9: src=DZ dst=p3 idx=16
10: src=RX dst=p4 idx=17
11: src=RY dst=p5 idx=18
12: src=RZ dst=p6 idx=19
13: src=DS dst=p7 idx=20
14: src=PREFERRED dst=preferred idx=21
15: src=COORD_OP_CODE dst=coord_op_code idx=1
Only 0 columns
Load srs db from: C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS Valmiera/apps/qgis/./resources/srs.db
Loaded 465/466 from C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\9.3\gdal-data\gcs.csv
Loaded 3790/3831 from C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\9.3\gdal-data\pcs.csv
Loaded 147/148 from C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\9.3\gdal-data\vertcs.csv
Loaded 61/62 from C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\9.3\gdal-data\compdcs.csv
Loaded 129/130 from C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\9.3\gdal-data\geoccs.csv
Loading epsg.wkt
Loading esri_extra.wkt
5044 WKTs loaded
CRS update (inserted:128 updated:147 deleted:1 errors:0)
275 CRSs updated.

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera>textreplace -std -t bin\qgis.bat 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera>textreplace -std -t bin\qgis-browser.bat 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera>REM get short path without blanks 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera>for %i in ("C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera") do set O4W_ROOT=%~fsi 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera>set O4W_ROOT=C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera>if not 1 == 0 mkdir "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\QGIS Valmiera" 
A subdirectory or file C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\QGIS Valmiera already exists.

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera>if not 1 == 0 nircmd shortcut "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera\bin\nircmd.exe" "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\QGIS Valmiera" "QGIS Desktop 2.2.0" "exec hide C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera\bin\qgis.bat" "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera\apps\qgis\icons\QGIS.ico" 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera>if not 1 == 0 nircmd shortcut "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera\bin\nircmd.exe" "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\QGIS Valmiera" "QGIS Browser 2.2.0" "exec hide C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera\bin\qgis-browser.bat" "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera\apps\qgis\icons\QGIS.ico" 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera>if not 1 == 0 nircmd shortcut "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera\bin\nircmd.exe" "~$folder.desktop$" "QGIS Desktop 2.2.0" "exec hide C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera\bin\qgis.bat" "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera\apps\qgis\icons\QGIS.ico" 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera>if not 1 == 0 nircmd shortcut "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera\bin\nircmd.exe" "~$folder.desktop$" "QGIS Browser 2.2.0" "exec hide C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera\bin\qgis-browser.bat" "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera\apps\qgis\icons\QGIS.ico" 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera>set OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS Valmiera 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera>textreplace -std -t "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera\apps\qgis\bin\qgis.reg" 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera>nircmd elevate "C:\Windows\regedit" /s "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera\apps\qgis\bin\qgis.reg" 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera>set OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS Valmiera 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera>textreplace -std -t "C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS Valmiera"\apps\Qt4\mkspecs\default\qmake.conf 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera>set OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS Valmiera 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera>textreplace -std -t "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS Valmiera"\bin\qt.conf 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera>if not 1 == 0 mkdir "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\QGIS Valmiera" 
A subdirectory or file C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\QGIS Valmiera already exists.

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera>if not 1 == 0 nircmd shortcut "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera\bin\nircmd.exe" "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\QGIS Valmiera" "SAGA GIS (2.0.8)" "exec hide """C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera\bin\saga_gui.bat"" -wx" "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera\apps\saga\saga_gui.exe" 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera>if not 1 == 0 nircmd shortcut "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera\bin\nircmd.exe" "C:\ProgramData\Desktop" "SAGA GIS (2.0.8)" "exec hide """C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera\bin\saga_gui.bat"" "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera\apps\saga\saga_gui.exe" 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera>nircmd shortcut "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera\bin\nircmd.exe" "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\QGIS Valmiera" "Setup" "exec hide ~qC:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera\bin\setup.bat~q -R ~qC:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera~q" "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera\OSGeo4W.ico" 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera>textreplace -std -t bin/setup.bat 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera>textreplace -std -t bin/setup-test.bat 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera>if not 1 == 0 mkdir "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\QGIS Valmiera" 
A subdirectory or file C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\QGIS Valmiera already exists.

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera>if not 1 == 0 xxmklink "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\QGIS Valmiera\OSGeo4W Shell.lnk" "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera\OSGeo4W.bat" " " \ "OSGeo for Windows command shell" 1 "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera\OSGeo4W.ico" 

XXMkLink     ver 1.00    (c)2005 Copyright  Pixelab, Inc.

The shortut created as follows

Shortcut path:     C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\QGIS Valmiera\OSGeo4W Shell.lnk
Target object:     C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera\OSGeo4W.bat
Arguments;          
Working Directory: \
Description:       OSGeo for Windows command shell
Display Mode:      Normal Window (1)
Icon file:         C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera\OSGeo4W.ico


C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera>if not 1 == 0 xxmklink "C:\ProgramData\Desktop\OSGeo4W Shell.lnk" "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera\OSGeo4W.bat" " " \ "OSGeo for Windows command shell" 1 "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera\OSGeo4W.ico" 

XXMkLink     ver 1.00    (c)2005 Copyright  Pixelab, Inc.

The shortut created as follows

Shortcut path:     C:\ProgramData\Desktop\OSGeo4W Shell.lnk
Target object:     C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera\OSGeo4W.bat
Arguments;          
Working Directory: \
Description:       OSGeo for Windows command shell
Display Mode:      Normal Window (1)
Icon file:         C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera\OSGeo4W.ico


C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera>set OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS Valmiera 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS Valmiera>textreplace -std -t apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\sipconfig.py
```